# Show Galois extension with $[K : F] = n$ has an intermediate filed with $L$ with $[K : L] = p$, where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

It is a two part question.

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension with $[K : F] = n$. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$, prove there is an intermediate field $L$ with $[K : L] = p$. 
Prove or disprove that there is an intermediate field $M$ with $[M : F] = p$.

Could anyone help me for some hints please, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** For the first part, use Cauchy's theorem and Galois' correspondence theorem.

Let me know if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, here is what I think from your hint: as $[K:F]=n$, we have $Gal(K/F)=n$, since $p|n$, then by Cauchy's theorem，$Gal(K/F)$ has an element (say $g$) of order $p$, so by Galois' correspondence theorem, there is a intermediate field $L$ fixed by $g$ with $[K:L]=p$? Am I right?

Comment: Perfect! :-) Don't forget the cardinality when you write $|Gal(K/F)|=n$.

Comment: Thank you! could you give me some hint for part two as well? Is it the statement true or false?

Comment: The second statement might be false, but I don't have counterexample right now. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, you’d want a subgroup with *index* $p$,and these will not necessarily exist, as, for instance, when $p=2$ and your Galois group is simple and noncyclic. For, a subgroup of index $2$ has to be normal.

Comment: +1 A nice and simple counterexample, I hadn't thought about it!